# How does an anonymous function work in onClick in React component?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, components

When there are two Button components in React, what is the difference between those two?

```
const add = (x, y) => {
  return x + y
}
```

Case 1:

```
<Button onClick={() => add(1, 2)}>Add</Button>
```

Case 2:

```
<Button onClick={add(1, 2)}>Add</Button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one will call `add(1, 2)` and return 3 to the caller of the `onClick` prop when the button is clicked.

The second one will call `add(1, 2)` when the JSX is *calculated* (most likely during render), and will pass `3` as the `onClick` prop. Case 2 is equivalent to:

```
<Button onClick={3}>Add</Button>
```

which is very likely not what you want.

You would usually invoke a function like that only when the function returns *another* function, eg:

```
const logNums = (x, y) => () => {
  console.log(x + y);
}
```

```
<Button onClick={logNums(1, 2)}>Add</Button>
```

which will log 3 when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

The differences are

```
const add = (x, y) => {
  return x + y
}
```

Case 1: this wait until the user click on the button it'll execute the call

```
<Button onClick={() => add(1, 2)}>Add</Button>
```

Case 2: This implementation will give error

```
<Button onClick={add(1, 2)}>Add</Button>
```

Case 2.1: This case will bind the function to the click listener

```
<Button onClick={add}>Add</Button>
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@omergoldberg/javascript-call-apply-and-bind-e5c27301f7bb

Answer (score 1):

```js
const add = (x, y) => {
  return x + y
}
```

In order to pass a value as a parameter through the onClick handler we pass in an arrow function which returns a call to the ***add*** function.

```js
<Button onClick={() => add(1, 2)}>Add</Button>
```

If no parameters are to be passed then you can call directly

```js
const add=()=>{
    return 2+3
}
```

```js
<Button onClick={add}>Add</Button>
```